# Git command within GitHub

Tags: git, github, history, git-reflog

In one of my repositories on GitHub, some commits are missing. I am pretty sure about it:

[image: contributions]

and clicking on the link "11 commits" yields a page with the message "No commits found for <user>". A possible cause is a `--force` commit that overwrote other commits.

Therefore I'd like to rummage around in the project's history including the dead branches, for example using `git reflog`. I can't do it by cloning or forking the project, because `reflog` acts on the *local* repository and therefore does not see the dead branches.

So: is there a way to run Git commands (here, `reflog`) directly on GitHub?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a way to clone the GitHub repository together with its dead branches?

Comment: Did you try `git clone --mirror`?

Comment: @jessehouwing. Thanks a lot for the advice. Unfortunately, a `git clone --mirror` followed by `git reflog show --all` returns an empty output. The GitHub version of the repo is really clean...

Comment: Cloning does not copy reflogs: you can't get vanished commits that way. GitHub do generally keep all commits forever by default (for various reasons) *and* in modern Git you can ask for any commit by its hash ID, but you must know the hash ID. If you do, use `git fetch origin <hash-id>:refs/heads/recovered-branch` for instance.

Comment: They don's happen to be committed to a fork? https://github.com/ivandalbosco/enu-mediation

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately the fork you mention is not relevant: the lost commits were created by a non-technical colleague (without any `git clone` command or fork action) directly on the GitHub GUI. My screenshot above prooves he really created commits.

Comment: @torek. Many thanks. Unfortunately, as the commits were created directly on the GitHub GUI, their SHA-1s have never been stored locally.

Comment: Contact GitHub support I suppose.